# A field's value should be either empty or valid ISBN

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-validator

**Form**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SourceForm {

    @ISBN(type = ISBN.Type.ANY)    
    private String isbn;
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "sources")
public class SourceEntity  extends BaseEntity{
    @ISBN(type = ISBN.Type.ANY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(255) default ''",
            nullable = false)
    private String isbn;   

}
```

**Problem**

Isbn field can be empty. In other words: either empty or valid ISBN.

But if I leave this field empty in the form, I get the error message "invalid ISBN".

What can I try next?

Comment: Quick bit of feedback Kifsif. I note that your questions have a tendency to be a bit chatty, and they strike me as a bit needy. Rather than asking how you, personally, can solve your problem with some assistance, you seem to want to give the problem to readers, so that it can be done for you, with a ribbon tied around it, and a nice bow in the ribbon. I appreciate it may feel like a practical short-term strategy to make appeals to readers' sympathy, but we might be doing you a favour if we encourage you to adopt a more self-sufficient mindset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of the `@ISBN` annotation is not to consider empty values as valid ISBNs. However, you can implement a custom validator to allow an empty value or validate ISBNs. Here's an example of how you can create a custom validator for this scenario:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { EmptyOrValidISBNValidator.class })
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface EmptyOrValidISBN {

    String message() default "Invalid ISBN";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And the implementation of the custom validator:

```
public class EmptyOrValidISBNValidator implements ConstraintValidator {
@Override
public void initialize(EmptyOrValidISBN constraintAnnotation) {
    // Initialization logic, if any
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String isbn, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    // Implement your own validation logic here
    // You can use the provided isbn parameter to validate if the ISBN is not empty or null, and if it is valid
    // Return true if the isbn is empty or valid, otherwise return false
    // For example, you can use regular expressions or external libraries to perform the ISBN validation

    // Validate if the ISBN is not empty or null and if it already exists
    if (Strings.isNotEmpty(isbn)) {
        return isValidIsbn10(isbn) || isValidIsbn13(isbn);
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isValidIsbn10(String isbn) {
    String regex = "^(?:\\d{9}[\\d|Xx])|(?:\\d{1,5}-\\d{1,7}-\\d{1,6}-[\\d|Xx])$";
    return Pattern.matches(regex, isbn);
}

private boolean isValidIsbn13(String isbn) {
    String regex = "^(?:\\d{12}\\d|[\\d|-]{1,5}-\\d{1,7}-\\d{1,6}-\\d)$";
    return Pattern.matches(regex, isbn);
}

}
```

You can then use the `@EmptyOrValidISBN` annotation on your field in your code, and the custom validator `EmptyISBNValidator` will allow empty values or valid ISBNs according to the defined logic.